# Deploying WebJobs from VS puts files in wrong folder

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I have created an App Service that contains three WebJobs that are triggered from queues:

> BlobContainer -> WJ1 -> Q1 -> WJ2 -> Q2 -> WJ3 -> (Released into the
>   wild)

When I deploy the WebJobs (Visual Studio) the exe, exe.config and pdb files of WJ2 are in both WJ2 and WJ3 directories. WJ3 dir contains its own files as well but this means that WJ3 is not being triggered correctly.

I have manually deleted the files from WJ3, removed my existing profiles and reset them. I have redeployed and the situation is the same. How do I resolve this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I was referencing one job from the other which then pulled in those files. The classes I was referencing were model type classes so I moved them into another project referencing them from there. I also had to delete existing files but after that no more problems all WebJobs triggerring properly.